# using a custom client in an existing FeignClient interface, with same target URL

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I have an existing interface annotated with `@FeignClient` :

```
@FeignClient(name = "myRemoteService", url = "${myRemoteService.url}/api/v3/", decode404 = true, configuration = MyRemoteServiceConfig.class)
public interface FeignRemoteService extends RemoteService
```

it has a bunch of methods that works fine.

Now, I need to add one method that doesn't fit in a simple @FeignClient. And I don't want the rest of my code to be aware of this and having to use another class than FeignRemoteService just for that use case, so I want to make it fit in the existing FeignRemoteService so that it's transparent for the classes that use it.

Use case is that I need to pass different credentials each time the method is called. To achieve that, I have created a default interface in which I put my custom code :

```
@Override
default UpdatedResource updateContent(String repoFullName, String path, MyStuff myStuff, String login, String password) {

    ContentClient contentClient = Feign.builder()
            .logger(new Slf4jLogger(ContentClient.class))
            .encoder(new JacksonEncoder())
            .decoder(new JacksonDecoder())
            .requestInterceptor(new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor(login, password))
            .logLevel(Logger.Level.FULL)
            .target(ContentClient.class, GlobalProperties.getRemoteServiceUrl() + "/api/v3/" + repoFullName + "/contents/" + path);

    return contentClient.updateContent(myStuff);

}
```

and an interface for the client :

```
interface ContentClient {
  @RequestLine("PUT")
  @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
  UpdatedResource updateContent(MyStuff myStuff);
}
```

It works, but I am not happy with the solution, as it's pretty ugly... I haven't find a nice way to inject *myRemoteService.url* in the custom Feign client that I build, somewhere closer from my code, than in a static variable in a GlobalProperties class.

Is there any better way of doing this, so that *myRemoteService.url* can be injected twice :

- in `@FeignClient` - no issue here.
- in a custom Feign client, built within a default method.

I am also open if there's a totally different approach, as long as everything is in the same service, so that the difference is hidden from the consumers.

Comment: I would use a different client, otherwise, you are outside of spring and there's nothing we can do.

Comment: I know.. but then it becomes very strange for the class using it, that needs 2 FeignClient as dependencies to interact with the same remote resource

Comment: This is where I advise to not use `@FeignClient` and just use the builder.

Comment: With straight Feign (built yourself via `new Feign.Builder()...build()`, you could use your own home-made `AuthCredentials` class (containing username and password) and a home-made `AuthCredentialsExpander implements Param.Expander` using `@Param(value = "credentials", expander = AuthCredentialsExpander.class) AuthCredentials credentials` and add the header param directly to the interface `@Headers("Authorization: {credentials}")`. But you will have to pass in the credentials to every such endpoint.

Comment: You could also roll your own authorization `RequestInterceptor` and annotate all your end points with `@Headers("Authorization: {basicAuth}")` or `@Headers("Authorization: {specialAuth}")` and have your interceptor check the "Authorization" header value and substitute the correct value.